# How do I clean reclaimed wood from construction?

Tags: wood, woodworking, recycling

I'm building a house (brick, cement and concrete) and I have a big pile of wood used for beam and pillar molds.

How can I properly clean cement off wood? I think it should be very damaging to blades in general (planer, table saw, etc), and sanding it out wouldn't be very effective.

Comment: Its too late now, oil (motor oil) wood before using as concrete form.

Comment: Do you need the wood at a standard size?  If not, resawing with a cheap blade (after knocking big pieces off, ala longneck)

Comment: Not really, is just wood that I want to re-use. In this case the problem is that I don't have a bandsaw. They don't have chunks of cement attached, is more like cement that was in contact, smeared or dripped.

Comment: @herrbag but then you're left with oil-soaked wood. Sounds worse that concrete. ;)

Comment: @DA01 you pretty much commit the lumber for form use. It would burn nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [X'Crete](http://www.cohills.com/pdf/Cohills_XCrete_TechSht.pdf) which is advertized as suited to removing concrete from forms.  It dissolves the concrete into a slush you can rinse away.  There's probably other similar products.

Or a more hard-core approach would be to use Muriatic Acid; apparently that's what masons use to clean their stuff.  Downside being it's dangerous.

A more tool-oriented approach would be a belt sander with a low grit paper.  Belt sander don't care.

Answer (score 0):

Knock it off with a chisel and a hammer, then plane it.

Comment: not with my planer

Comment: Edit: Knock it off with a chisel and hammer, then plane it using the plane you borrowed from that neighbor you don't like.